# How to update CentOS 6.5 to kernel 2.6.32-431?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, yum

I need to update my CentOS 6.5 kernel to `2.6.32-431`. Running `yum clean all && yum update` doesn't do it for me.

How do I update? And what could be the issue?

```
[root@centos64 ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64
[root@centos64 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
[root@centos64 ~]# yum clean all && yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning repos: base epel extras updates
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                                                       | 8.1 kB     00:00
 * base: centosz3.centos.org
 * epel: fedora.mirror.nexicom.net
 * extras: mirror.linux.duke.edu
 * updates: centosb5.centos.org
base                                                                                                                                | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                                                                                     | 4.4 MB     00:00
epel                                                                                                                                | 4.4 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                     | 6.1 MB     00:01
extras                                                                                                                              | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                                                                                   |  19 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                             | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                  | 2.6 MB     00:00
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
[root@centos64 ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64
```

I'm running a VM at http://cloudatcost.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing `yum update`, you need to restart the machine: `reboot now`

Then you'll be able to see the new kernel with `uname -r`

Answer (score 2):

When `yum` insists there are no packages to be updated, check if kernel is not excluded from updates: In `/etc/yum.conf`, there is usually a line similar to

```
exclude=kernel*
```

You need to remove `kernel` from the list or, if it is the only entry in the exclude list, remove the line completely or comment it out using `#`.

Then, `yum update` (or `yum update kernel`) should work properly. (Then, check the default in `/etc/grub.conf` and do not forget to reboot.)

Answer (score 0):

Download rpm package for 2.6.32-431 and install using command

```
rpm -ivh kernel new version
```

and change preference to new kernel to default=0 in grub configuration file.

```
vi /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the current kernel RPM package to see which kernel is installed

```
rpm -qa| grep kernel-2.6.32-431
```

If a new RPM is available install it, and then reboot your OS and check loaded kernel as below:

```
uname -r
```